# Joomla - Multiple Instances of Module Divs

Tags: joomla, module, position

I'm used to using Joomla 1.5, and am trying to switch to 2.5.

I have 2 modules in the right position, I expect that there would be 2 boxes (which is what I want), one box for each module. But for some reason it's just adding the second module to the first box.

It's not copying the divs (main_top_box, main_mid_box, main_bottom_box) inside the if statement: `<?php if($this->countModules('right')) { ?>`, instead it's just putting the `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right"/>` commands side by side.

You were able to do this with the code I've used in Joomla 1.5. Have they removed this functionality?

Here's what I see:

[image]

Here's what I should see:

[image]

Joomla Code:

```
  <?php if($this->countModules('right')) { ?>
        <div class="main_top_box">
          <div class="main_mid_box">
            <div class="main_bottom_box">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Code Output(Source):

```
<div class="main_top_box">
  <div class="main_mid_box">
    <div class="main_bottom_box">
      <div class="custom"  >
        <h3>Services</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Family Law</li>
          <li>Collaborative Law</li>
          <li>Real Estate</li>
          <li>Wills</li>
          <li>Estate Planning</li>
          <li>Estates</li>
        </ul>
        <p> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="custom"  >
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Testing the Right Box</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should Be(Source):

```
<div class="main_top_box">
  <div class="main_mid_box">
    <div class="main_bottom_box">
        <h3>Services</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Family Law</li>
          <li>Collaborative Law</li>
          <li>Real Estate</li>
          <li>Wills</li>
          <li>Estate Planning</li>
          <li>Estates</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main_top_box">
  <div class="main_mid_box">
    <div class="main_bottom_box">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Testing the Right Box</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve nor what your actual question is

Comment: I have edited my original question, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: At the moment, you have `<div class="custom">` inside the actual module presumably and the 3 `<div>` tags above that in the template index.php, so could you also add the 3 `<div>` tags inside the module and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by these to methods

1. Either Change the order of display the module in the same position in the module manager.
2. Create separate module position for both the modules and assign them accordingly.

Comment: 1. Changing the order just changes which one shows at the top of the box. It doesn't solve my issue.
2. Creating separate modules disables the whole dynamic content aspect that I'm trying to achieve. The whole point is that you can add as many items to the 'right' module and they will each show up in their own box. This was achievable in Joomla 1.5, I used it all of the time. Thus I'm not sure why it isn't working now.